# Exporting file from SAS, passing log/pass in script

Tags: sas

For example, i want the file `_PRODSAVAIL` being exported to shared folder, which is secured by log/pass. How can i set log/pass in script?

```
PROC EXPORT datafile="\\10.48.42.166\export\november.csv" 
     out=work._PRODSAVAIL
     dbms=csv
     replace;
     getnames=yes;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a SAS question, you just need to set up your environment so that SAS can write to that location before you run the program.

See this answer to a similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/344775/passing-unc-username-and-password-within-a-unc-path

To summarise, if you're on Windows you run a 'net use' command to give your credentials before running the SAS program.